# Python Scraping with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

```
<td class="user-info">
<div class="id" title="Player ID">1211</div>
<div class="name" title="PName">Ronaldo</div>
</td>
```

I wanted to scrape the 1211 in "Player ID" but couldn't. Here is my code so far:

```
adressyr = urllib2.urlopen("WEBSITE")
soup = BeautifulSoup(adressyr, 'html.parser')
mydivs = soup.findAll("td", { "class" : "Player ID" })
print mydivs
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class of that div is not `Player ID` but `id`. Try:

```
adressyr = urllib2.urlopen("WEBSITE")
soup = BeautifulSoup(adressyr, 'html.parser')
mydivs = soup.findAll("td", { "class" : "id" })
print mydivs
```